# C++: Deconstructors getting called before exiting the scope

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Why does the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class A {
    public:
    A() {cout << "A constructor\n";}
    ~A() {cout << "A deconstructor\n";}
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    B() {cout << "B constructor\n";}
    ~B() {cout << "B deconstructor\n";}
};

class C : public B {
    public:
    C() {cout << "C constructor\n";}
    ~C() {cout << "C deconstructor\n";}
};

int main() {
    A a = C();
    cout << "Exiting scope of main!" << endl;
}
```

Output this:

```
A constructor
B constructor
C constructor
C deconstructor
B deconstructor
A deconstructor
Exiting scope of main!
A deconstructor
```

Note: if you replace the first line in main with `A* a = new C();`, the output is as expected:

```
A constructor
B constructor
C constructor
Exiting scope of main!
```

The expected behavior was for constructors A, B and C to get called upon initializing a, and for the deconstructor to only be called after exiting the scope.

Comment: A side note: why do you use `A a = C();` ? in order to use polymorphism you need a pointer/reference. Your code performs slicing.

Comment: There are two objects; the temporary `C` and the `A` it gets copied into. The lifetime of the `C` instance ends after the initialization of `a`, and the lifetime of `a` ends with the closing `}`  of `main`.

Comment: Incidentally, the more common nomenclature is "destructor" not "deconstructor".

Answer (score 1):

`A a = C();` is **copy initialization** which means that the object `a` is created as a copy of the expression `C()`. Now, the copy constructor `A::A(const A&)` expects an argument of type `A` since it  has a parameter of type `const A&`.

This in turn means that the expression on the right hand side must somehow be convertible to `A`. And this *implicit conversion* is possible as `C` is a base of `B` which in turn is a base of `A`. That is, a `C` object can be implicitly converted to an `A`.

Finally, the result of that conversion will be an `A` object that will be used to **copy initialize** `a`.

You can confirm this by adding a copy constructor for your class `A` as shown below. Also since the order of destruction is reverse to the order of construction, we will get the output shown in your program. In particular the order of construction was `A > B > C` therefore when at the **end of full expression** `A a = C();`, we get the destructor call in the reverse order as `C < B < A`.

Then finally when the `main` scope exits, the object `a` is destructed and we get the destructor call for that object.

```
class A {
    public:
    A() {cout << "A constructor " << this << " " << "\n";}
    ~A() {cout << "A deconstructor " << this << " " << "\n";}
    A(const A&arg){cout << "A copy constructor " << this << " " << &arg << " " << "\n";}
};

class B : public A {
    public:
    B() {cout << "B constructor " << this << " " << "\n";}
    ~B() {cout << "B deconstructor " << this << " " << "\n";}
};

class C : public B {
    public:
    C() {cout << "C constructor " << this << " " << "\n";}
    ~C() {cout << "C deconstructor " << this << " " << "\n";}
};

int main() {
    A a = C();
    cout << "Exiting scope of main!" << endl;
}
```

The output of the above program is:

```
A constructor 0x7ffec7a013b7                     //A object is created first 
B constructor 0x7ffec7a013b7                     //next B object is created
C constructor 0x7ffec7a013b7                     //third C object is created
A copy constructor 0x7ffec7a013b6 0x7ffec7a013b7 //the A object created at the beginning is used here 
C deconstructor 0x7ffec7a013b7                   //at end of full expression C is destroyed first
B deconstructor 0x7ffec7a013b7                   //then B is destroyed
A deconstructor 0x7ffec7a013b7                   //finally A is destroyed last as it was created first
Exiting scope of main!
A deconstructor 0x7ffec7a013b6                   //at main exit the only remaining object a is destroyed
```